# Бесконечный "Performing system checks..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Развернул проект, в котором 200+ джанго app'ок. При запуске через runserver system checks длится "бесконечно". Жду уже около часа.

Когда запускаю manage.py check, выдаёт вот это:
`django.db.utils.InternalError: ОШИБКА:  текущая транзакция прервана, команды до конца блока транзакции игнорируются`

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в миграциях. После дропа базы заново накатил миграции, и залил дамп, после чего всё заработало